Do Thread Unsafe STL Functions Used In DLL Share Memory With EXE?
If I use a thread unsafe STL function in my DLL (for example std::localtime which uses memory shared between threads) do I have to worry about threads started by the executable interfering with me calling such a function in a thread safe way?
For example, let's assume I use a mutex lock to protect my calls to std::localtime in my DLL (so that only a single DLL thread can call that function at any time).  Would that be safe to do?  Or is the memory used internally by std::localtime also shared with the executable threads, meaning there is no way to safely call std::localtime without some way of synchronizing with the executable threads?

When you use a library ALL functions are considered to be "not threadsafe" unless explicitly documented that they are. So yes in general you do have to take care that only one thread calls them at a time. std::scoped_lock + std::mutex are a safe way to do that.

Your suspicion is right, there is nothing syncing or separating the calls from inside your DLL and those inside other DLLs or the main executable. This can be fixed (at least in your code) with a different design approach: Instead of using those global, shared objects, you use dependency injection. In this case, you require something that can convert the time_t value as parameter to your DLL methods. This would be an abstract interface, which can then be implemented in a thread-safe way.

The term STL is obsolete - it was a library that predated (and influenced specification of) the C++ standard library, and also predated support of multithreading in the C++ standard. If you actually have a (pre-2000) compiler bundled with any STL version, it is almost certainly not thread safe. It takes significant effort to ensure any part of any library is thread safe - so, if (any part of) the library you are using is thread safe, that will be documented - as it is a significant selling point. Conversely, if documentation does not mention thread safety, assume it is NOT thread safe.
